# Can you scale individual hue variables in a Seaborn pointplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm trying to scale individual hue variables in a Seaborn pointplot by different amounts, and I can't find how to go about that (I'm new to Seaborn, apologies if this is a basic question).

For example, I have

```
pointplot(x='date', y='charge', hue='channel', data=mydataframe)
```

Which plots the charge of 7 different "channels." I want to multiply the charge values for channel 1 by a certain amount, the charge values for channel 2 by a different amount, etc. Is there a good way to go about this?

EDIT: modifying the dataframe is definitely the way to go, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should make the modification in your data frame prior to plotting

Comment: That makes sense, I probably should have realized that before. Thank you!